# Can someone explain me this part of array indexing?

Tags: arrays, image, matlab, matrix

I'm trying to manipulate an image with MATLAB, I want to flip the image without the function flip, so I found this, If someone knows how does it work can explain me?

```
img(:,(end:-1:1),:,:);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it yourself, see the example below:

```
A = 1:10
A(end:-1:1)
A =

     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
ans =

    10     9     8     7     6     5     4     3     2    1
```

`end` is the last element of the array, `start:step:end` creates an array starting at `start`, ending at `end` with step size `step`. Setting the step negative flips the array. This can be done across all dimensions of an array, so across the second in your case.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer I appreciate it, It was what I was looking for, is there a way to put it in a for cycle?

Comment: @LaloRivera of course, `for idx = 1:10; A = 1:10; A(end:-1:1);  end`. But without joking, that's A) way too vague and broad a question for Stack Overflow and B) a separate question altogether. Please keep posts on Stack Overflow to 1-post-1-question, i.e. ask a separate one if you have problems implementing a `for` loop.